# Outlook Client Connection Status

Tags: vba, outlook, connection, client, status

I need a way to programmatically get the Outlook Connection Status.
Specifically, if you hold ctrl and click the outlook systray icon, you have a connection status option.
If you use that, it shows all sorts of outlook connection status to exchange.
I need to get that data but I need to log it or be able to pull it programmatically

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are interested in the [ExchangeConnectionMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/outlook-vba/articles/namespace-exchangeconnectionmode-property-outlook?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm776)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) property of the `Namespace` or `Account` classes. It returns an `OlExchangeConnectionMode` constant that indicates the current connection mode for the Microsoft Exchange Server that hosts the account mailbox.

If the `ExchangeConnectionMode` property is `olOffline` or `olDisconnected` , the `NameSpace.Offline` property returns `True` . If the `ExchangeConnectionMode` property is `olOnline` , `olConnected` , or `olConnectedHeaders` , the `NameSpace.Offline` property returns `False` .

```
 Sub MarkHighImportance() 
   Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
   Dim mpfInbox As Outlook.Folder 
   Dim obj As Object 
   Dim ctr As Integer 
   Dim i As Integer 
   Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
   Set mpfInbox = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 
   ctr = mpfInbox.Items.count 
   If (myNamespace.ExchangeConnectionMode = olConnectedHeaders) Then 
     For i = 1 To ctr 
       Set obj = mpfInbox.Items.Item(i) 
       If (obj.Importance <> olImportanceHigh And obj.DownloadState = olHeaderOnly) Then 
         obj.MarkForDownload = olMarkedForDownload 
       End If 
     Next 
   End If 
 End Sub
```

Comment: I'm interested in getting the Avg Resp and Avg Proc for each connection

Comment: The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that.